# asp.net mvc 4 many-to-many relation how do I insert data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, insert, many-to-many

how do I insert data in many to many relationship?
I have these two models definded by this code

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Anotation { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleTagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Now the big Q is how to seed the database with test data. I have some experience with normal tables and queries and in MVC EF I am quite a novice. Normally I would create an association table and in it define the link between these models. But I have read many tutorials and none gave me a deterministic way how to do it, so I you can imagine my confusion.

As I said before, I "created" an assoc table via ModelBuilder and that's where I end :(

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().
            HasMany(at => at.ArticleTags).WithMany(a => a.Articles).
            Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ArticleID").MapRightKey("ArticleTagID").ToTable("Articles_To_ArticleTags"));
    }
}
```

I need to know the easiest way to seed my DB (don't care if have to delete the assoc table) and understand how it works in the MVC - linking the two models, linking two specific instances, ... , and how to code it all.

Thx for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally solved!
Found a good post [here](http://justmycode.blogspot.cz/2012/05/learning-mvc-code-first-and-many-to.html) and with [this one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) together I made it work.

In short what I had to do:

1. **Remove my builder link** - EF itself creates link (own assoc table)
2. A little modify models
3. Create **DatabaseInitializer**
4. In the Global.asax to the method Application_Start() add **Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());** declaration
5. don't forget to se **ConnectionString** and **DBcontext**
6. Normally use in a View

**Modifications** in constructor (not sure if absolutely necessary, maybe it does the same thing as native/default constructor):

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Anotation { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string SourceLink { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }

    public Article()
    {
        ArticleTags = new List<ArticleTag>();
    }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleTagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

    public ArticleTag()
    {
        Articles = new List<Article>();
    }
}
```

And the **DatabaseInitializer**

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        ArticleTag tag1= new ArticleTag { TagName = "aaaa" };
        ArticleTag tag2= new ArticleTag { TagName = "bbbb" };
        ArticleTag tag3= new ArticleTag { TagName = "cccc" };
        var articleTags = new List<ArticleTag> { tag1, tag2, tag3};
        articleTags.ForEach(i => context.ArticleTags.Add(i));
        context.SaveChanges();


        Article a1 = new Article
        {
            Title = "Title1",
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Anotation = "Anotation1",
            Body = "article_1",
            ArticleTags = new List<ArticleTag> { tag1 }
        };
        Article a2 = new Article
        {
            Title = "Title12",
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Anotation = "Anotation2",
            Body = "article_2",
            ArticleTags = new List<ArticleTag> { tag2, tag3 }
        };
        var articles = new List<Article> { a1, a2 };
        articles.ForEach(a => context.Articles.Add(a));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: off course, in the 4th step you'll probably need to add some using* statements